Debug Pre-POST Freeze with ASUS Prime B350 PLUS
Last night I powered down my gaming rig to hibernate, business as usual.
This morning I turned it on, and my screen stays black. Not even the BIOS POST screen would show. Screen goes to Power Saving mode immediately.
I tried:

several reboots (both warm and completely cold)
switching to another monitor
connecting both monitors via HDMI and Display Port
remove all RAM modules but one (tried all 4 by themselves)
remove my RTX 3080 and replace it with my old GTX 1080
remove all HDDs, SSDs and Nvme M.2

No luck!
My last bet is on the CPU (or the mainboard itself) but I do not have a spare one to cross check.
Is there a way to „debug“ the boot sequence of the Prime B350? How would you go about it?

If the computer doesn't POST, this is probably a hardware problem. Take it to a repair-shop that will have the tools and replacement parts to locate and fix the problem. It will be more economical than replacing parts randomly.

It's always a good idea to keep one PC mobo speaker buzzer in your kit. https://i.imgur.com/YxYtXWW.png It comes in handy to test if BIOS or CPU  is ok or not. Plug it into the mobo buzzer pins, boot without RAM and see if it gives beeps for missing RAM.

FYI: Turns out the CPU was faulty. Never had that before! One day it works, the other day its broken. But hey, such is life!

Switch Normal to Asus Optimal in UEFI it should work. You can find that settings top right side in Main Menu
